# dividing an integer by double loses precision

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to divide an integer by a double value but i believe its losing precision..

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    double t=5465/54.0;
    double t1=(double)5465/(double)(t);
    double t3 = 5465.0/101.203;
    printf("%lf %lf %lf\n",t,t1,t3);
    return 0;
}
```

For the above code value of `t3 = 54.0003` is as expected but for t1 it becomes `54` instead of getting same value as t3. 
I can't get what mistake am i doing

Comment: *5465/(5465/54.0)* is equal to *54*, so I don't see why you are surprised that you get that result. You get exactly the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of 5465/54.0 is 101.203703704 (to 9 decimal places). In your code you are using this

```
 double t3 = 5465.0/101.203;
```

truncating the result of

```
 double t=5465/54.0;
```

to `101.203` for some unknown reason. Therefore you are calculating 2 different values as a result of the truncation. Essentially you are expecting these 2 calculations to be the same but

```
 5465.0/101.203 != 5465/101.203703704
```

Comment: Thanks .. i got the result also by not rounding off ..i.e making t = 5465/54

Answer (score 1):

Of course the results are going to differ. You used 101.203 instead of 101.203703704.